# Javascript Regular expression to get all media queries from Css

Tags: javascript, regex

I was trying to remove all `@media{..}` blocks from my css file using javascript.

I tried something like this `str.replace(/\@media[^\}]*\}}/g,'')`,but this only works with something like

`@media screen and (max-width:400px){@-ms-viewport{width:320px}}` and not with

`@media screen and (min-width:768px){.tron{padding:50px 60px;border-radius:6px}.tron h1{font-size:63px}}`

How can I replace all the media blocks from the CSS file?
Can this be done using javascript RegExp or I have to manually loop through it?

Comment: have you seen the css parse library?

Comment: @DanielA.White No, any link?

Comment: This is the node package, but it can be used in the browser. https://npmjs.org/package/css

Comment: When are you planning to do that? Before you apply? Because once the CSS has been read by the browser it is too late

Comment: @mplungjan its not for the current css file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood you correctly you just need a non-greedy matching:

```
str.replace(/@media.*?}}/g,'')
```